# A Hollow Sphere

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Imagine a sphere with a hole that has been drilled clean through its center (i.e. a cylindrical piece of the sphere is now missing). This new shape, with the core missing, has height of 6 when standing on the ground (i.e. flat side on the ground). What is the volume of this shape?

Comment: Are you sure this has a unique solution? My first guess is that it depends on the diameter of the drill.

Comment: @Glorfindel It does indeed have a unique solution and no additional information is needed to solve it. The simplicity of this question is why I love it so much

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_ring_problem Here is the answer.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I was hoping people who hadn't heard this question  before would be able to derive some enjoyment from solving it. But I'm new to the site, and maybe that was an unreasonable thing to hope for since it is a fairly well known question. Anyway, seeing as I can't accept your comment, how do you suggest I proceed?

Comment: @Dsel: That's the problem with popular problems, they can easily be googled. And since a comment cannot be accepted, maybe I'll post an answer, mark it as community wiki and then you can accept it.

Comment: @CodeNewbie That makes sense, I'll be more careful to avoid this sort of the thing in the future. I can also just remove the question if you think that's better. I'll leave it up to you since you've been around the site much longer than me

Comment: @Dsel: Don't be disheartened. I don't think this is a bad question, it reminded me of this problem that I had encountered years ago, so that was a good trip down memory lane. What you could do in the future is rehash the question by adding some creative fluff, so that the underlying problem is not immediately visible.

Comment: As it stands, googling the words ["Volume of a drilled sphere"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=volume%20of%20a%20drilled%20sphere) is enough to bring up the solution. With a creative story, one will not know right away what keywords to use in their google search.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I'll definitely incorporate that advice in the future. And don't worry, not discouraged at all. Thanks for being patient!

Comment: similar riddle: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11813/what-are-the-weights-of-the-bangles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a popular problem commonly referred to as the Napkin ring problem.

Essentially, irrespective of the diameter of the drilled cylinder, the volume of the resultant object will always be equal to the volume of a sphere whose diameter is the same length as the height of the object. In this case, the volume of the sphere is $4/3\pi (6/2)^3$ or roughly 113.1 cubic units, no matter what the diameter of the original sphere was. As long as it was drilled out perfectly till the height of the new object is 6, the volume remains the same.

[Here is the Wikipedia entry outlining the problem and its solution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_ring_problem)